# Waswas Related question

Tags: doubts, waswasa

What is the best on getting rid of waswas and how to ingnore will by prayer be accepted? If I actually did pronounce it wrong but ignored it thinking it's waswas

Answer (score 1):

Allah knows your intention, he knows best what is in your heart, as long as you hate those thoughts you are not sinful for this, so whenever these thoughts come to your mind immediately start thinking about something else, engage yourself in something like painting, reading, cooking, playing,  stitching, writing,  talking so that you can get rid of these thoughts, because in free time there are more chances of those thoughts to come to your mind. And about salah, you should study the meaning of surahs and duas that you recite in salah so that you can get rid of these thoughts in your salah, concentrate every word in your salah, so whenever these thoughts come to your mind in salah don't try to ignore them just try to focus on the meanings of surahs and duas in salah

Answer (score 0):

Reading more Quran and doing more dhikr. Reciting adhkar and increasing your general knowledge of Islam. You could also seek help from scholars as they are very knowledgeable and could help you as well.